# facing error in Infinite scrolling using playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, playwright, playwright-python

How can i include infinite loading using playwright i have tried many solutions that i got online but none of them solved my issue

[This is how it looks like it dosen't load the whole page instead it gives an Timeout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thIop.png)

Below is the code that displays all the cards of the specific page

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import pandas as pd

def main():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        chromium_path = r"C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-1076\chrome-win\chrome.exe"
        browser = p.chromium.launch(executable_path=chromium_path, headless=False)

        page_url = f'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Tourist-Attraction/nct-10596038'

        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(page_url, timeout=600000)

        attractions = page.locator('//div[@class="jsx-a3a43292cc1e6428 results_listing_container"]/div').all()
        print(f'There are: {len(attractions)} attractions.')

        attractions_list =[]
        for attraction in attractions:
            attraction_dict = {} 
            attraction_dict['place'] = attraction.locator('//div[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad"]/h2/a').inner_text()


            attractions_list.append(attraction_dict)
        df = pd.DataFrame(attractions_list)
        df.to_excel('attractions_list.xlsx', index=False)
        df.to_csv('attractions_list.csv', index=False)

        browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's one of the code that i tried

```
for i in range(5): #make the range as long as needed
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
    
    time.sleep(15)
```

I am not able to figure out what's the problem in here I just want all the attractions to be loaded and not just the start 10 . My code gives output as 10 and throws an timeout error

here's the error

```
PS C:\Users\pranit\OneDrive\Desktop\BeautifulSoup tutorial> python -u "c:\Users\pranit\OneDrive\Desktop\BeautifulSoup tutorial\TravelAdvisorAttractions.py"
There are: 10 attractions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pranit\OneDrive\Desktop\BeautifulSoup tutorial\TravelAdvisorAttractions.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\pranit\OneDrive\Desktop\BeautifulSoup tutorial\TravelAdvisorAttractions.py", line 20, in main
    attraction_dict['place'] = attraction.locator('//div[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad"]/h2/a').inner_text()
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 17228, in inner_text
    self._sync(self._impl_obj.inner_text(timeout=timeout))
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 109, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_locator.py", line 444, in inner_text
    return await self._frame.inner_text(
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 619, in inner_text
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 482, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "C:\Users\pranit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 97, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("xpath=//div[@class=\"jsx-a3a43292cc1e6428 results_listing_container\"]/div").first.locator("xpath=//div[@class=\"jsx-4d407376001b01ad\"]/h2/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less this is what you want:

```
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()

    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Tourist-Attraction/nct-10596038')

    # We get alll the cards (10 at the beginning)
    cards = page.locator("//*[@class='jsx-a3a43292cc1e6428 results_listing_container']/div")

    # We repeat the process till we have 100 cards (Which is the maximum)
    while len(cards.all()) < 100:
        # We do scroll to the last present card
        # In the first while loop it will be scroll to the card 10, second loop will be scroll to the card 20 and so on
        cards.all()[-1].scroll_into_view_if_needed()
        time.sleep(2)

    # Once we have 100 cards, we print the info of every card (Here you can investigate in order to show the info that you want, in the example I am showing everything
    for card in cards.all():
        print(card.inner_text())
        print("------------------------------O--------------------------------")
```

I explained the code with comments.

I noticed that the page sometimes gets stuck waiting for loading the new cards, if that happen you must investigate a way of managing it.

But well, at least with that you can get all the cards of the page.